# How do I create a vector of object values from a vector of object pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

The "naive" solution is;

```
std::vector<T> vector_of_objects;
vector_of_objects.reserve(vector_of_pointers.size());
for (T const * p : vector_of_pointers)
    vector_of_objects.push_back(*p);
```

The above seems cumbersome and perhaps not immediately obvious.

Is there a solution that is at least not significantly less efficient and perhaps a little quicker and more intuitive? I'm thinking C++11 might have a solution that I am not aware of...

Comment: With Boost.Iterator: `std::vector<T> vo(boost::make_transform_iterator(vp.begin(), deref), boost::make_transform_iterator(vp.end(), deref));` where `auto deref = [](T* p) -> T& { return *p; };`.

Comment: Or using standard C++ only: `std::transform(vp.begin(), vp.end(), std::back_inserter(vo), deref);`

Comment: @DieterLücking if you could point out the mistake I would appreciate it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with writing loops.

Comment: @DieterLücking Ah thanks I didn't see the missing `.size()` but I don't see the problem with the `T* const p`, seems legit to me...

Comment: @DieterLücking how's that?

Comment: @Xeo The problem is that there isn't a standard `deref`.  If you've already got one in your toolkit, then that's the obvious solution.  If you have to write one just for this case, or use a lambda, the choice is less obvious (but I still find the `transform` version better, because the function name documents what you're doing.)

Comment: @JamesKanze re: "there isn't a standard `deref`". Which is amusing/peculiar considering there is a standard `addressof`.

Comment: @screwnut Why?  You need `addressof` in order to obtain the address of an object which might have an overloaded `operator&`, because there is a built-in `&` operator for _all_ types.  The only types which have a built-in `*` operator are pointers, and you can't change its meaning, so you never need a special function to get the built-in value.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for explaining why `deref` is not a necessary counterpart to `addressof`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Does writing everything in one line mean shorter code? No.

In my opinion these two lines are shorter and more readable:

```
for (auto p : vector_of_pointers)

    vector_of_objects.emplace_back(*p);
```

Function [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is not shorter than ranged-based loop, sometime it's bigger due to passing lambda expressions.

Function [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is even longer than `std::for_each`, however the word *transform* is an advantage to find out what's happening in the following.

Comment: I'd rather use `emplace_back` (more opportunities for optimization) but other than that +1. I find this much more readable than `transform` etc.

Comment: The advantage of std::transform is that it automatically handles preallocation for you.

Comment: @JanHudec: Do you mean it would allocate memory for destination if it hasn't enough space? No, it doesn't.

Comment: @MM. This is probably the best answer, but it's not what I was hoping for. I don't care whether or not everything can be crammed on a single line - I wanted a solution that is more intuitive and preallocates memory the way my "naive" solution does. It seems like such a solution simply doesn't exist so I'll mark this as the answer, as it addresses the reasons why my question can't be answered as I had initially desired.

Comment: @ausairman: Why do you think your solution is _naive_? It's short, readable and correct.

Comment: @MM. simply because it is the solution someone who was *writing* the code would come up with, and the purpose of which is perhaps not immediately obvious to someone *reading* the code. I know I'm being picky here, I guess I was just hoping there was something more elegant. But this is fine.

Comment: @MM. I mean that `std::transform` with `std::back_inserter` does `reserve` on the output collection if the output collection supports it and the input iterator is random access (so the range size can be measured easily) in good implementations of standard C++ library (no, that's not specified anywhere and it does not have to, but at least GNU stdlibc++ will).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the correct way. Another way is to use built-in algorithms library, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // Create a vector of pointers
    std::vector<int*> vptr;
    vptr.push_back(new int(1));
    vptr.push_back(new int(2));

    // Copy to vector of objects
    std::vector<int> vobj;
    std::for_each(vptr.begin(), vptr.end(), [&](int *n) { vobj.emplace_back(*n); });

    // Free the pointers
    std::for_each(vptr.begin(), vptr.end(), [&](int *n) { delete n; });

    // Print out the vector of objects
    std::copy(vobj.begin(), vobj.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for_each` doesn't say anything about what is going on.  `std::transform` is the appropriate function here.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way would be to use `std::transform`:

```
std::transform( vector_of_pointers.begin(),
                vector_of_pointers.end(),
                std::back_inserter( vector_of_objects ),
                []( T* p ) { return *p; } );
```

Whether this is "better" than what you've written is another
question: it has the advantage of being idiomatic, and of
actually naming what is going on (which makes the code slightly
clearer).  On the other hand, the "transformation" is very, very
simple, so it would be easily recognized in the loop, and the
new form for writing such loops makes things fairly clear as
well.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to call the copy-ctor as in your solution, there's no way around that.

Comment: Well, but that's the thing that C++ does implicitly. The point is to get rid of the loop, which is definitely possible.

Comment: @JanHudec Since you have to call the copy constructor of every object in the vector, the loop in inavoidable. Either you write it down explicitly or use an algorithm function or iterator which has a loop somewhere in its implementation.

Comment: Sure, there will be a loop. But it whether you write it manually or not is the key question here.

Comment: @JanHudec the OP specifically is asking about speed, you're going on about code form.

Comment: @PaulEvans: Did you read the same question as me? He's specifically asking for something "more intuitive", with the proviso that it shouldn't be significantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<T*> vecPointers;
std::vector<T> vecValues;

for(size_t x=0;x<vecPointers.size();x++)
{
    vecValues.push_back(*vecPointers[x]);
}
```

I believe that if type T is a custom object then you will need to create a copy constructor for class T.

```
class T
{
    private:
        int someValue;
    public:
        T()
        {
        }
        T(const T &o)// copy constructor
        {
            someValue = o.someValue;
        }
        virtual ~T()
        {
        }
};
```

Comment: Or the compiler generated copy constructor does the job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the real question is whether you're doing this often enough for it to be worth writing extra code in one place to clean up the code in the other places.

I can imagine writing a `deref_iterator` that would allow you to do something like this:

```
std::vector<T> vector_of_objects{
    deref_iterator(std::begin(vector_of_pointers)), 
    deref_iterator(std::end(vector_of_pointers))};
```

Now, we're left with the question of whether this is really shorter than the original loop or not. In terms of simple number of key strokes, it's probably going to depend on the names you give things. If you didn't care about readable names, it could be:

```
vector<T> v_o{d(begin(v_p)), d(end(v_p))};
```

The short names obviously make it short, but I certainly wouldn't advise them -- if I hadn't just typed this in, I'd have no clue in the world what it meant. A longer name (that needs to be repeated a couple of times) obviously adds more key-strokes, but I can't imagine anybody thinking the readability wasn't worth it.

In any case, the `deref_iterator` itself would clearly take up some code. An iterator has enough boiler-plate that it typically takes around 100 lines of code or so. Let's (somewhat arbitrarily) decide that this saves one line of code every time you use it. On that basis, you'd have to use it 100 times to break even.

I'm not sure that's accurate in characterizing the code overall -- the code for an iterator is mostly boiler-plate, and other than a typo, there's not much that could really go wrong with it. For the most part, it would be a matter of including the right header, and using it, not of virtually ever having to look at the code for the iterator itself.

That being the case, I might accept it as an improvement even if the *total* number of lines of code increased. Writing it to use only once would clearly be a loss, but I don't think it'd need to be a full 100 times to qualify as breaking even either.